# JQuery's ajax function stripping HTML tags from XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

Okay, I'm pulling data from an XML file to populate my elements of my webpage dynamically.  My problem is that when I use JQuery .ajax to pull the xml file, it strips my HTML tags.

For example,

**Data in XML file:**

```
<transcript><p>Hello, world</p></transcript>
```

**Desired output on webpage:**

```
<p>Hello, world</p>
```

**Actual output:**

```
Hello World
```

Here is my code inside of my ajax function:

```
$(xmlData).find('item').each(function() {
        var n = $(this).find('transcript').text();
```

I've tried to use JQuery's '.html()' but it returns null.  What is the *simplest way* I can fix this? Preferably without changing too much of what I've already done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @roasted No it doesn't. Look at the API docs for `.html` - it's not supported with XML docs

Comment: Your xml doesn't use CDATA sections to separate html content from xml tags? This is asking for trouble...

Comment: Not sure why you're having a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qe7GB/

Comment: @roasted I would've expected `.html` to work too, but it says no in jQuery docs

Comment: @ExplosionPills Is that an XML doc? Nope, it's a string. Totally different

Comment: @Ian sorry I didn't realize that they actually do get handled differently; is there any way to create an XML doc in JavaScript?

Comment: @ExplosionPills No problem, yeah Javascript has support for modifying them in a similar manner to modifying the DOM. But here's something you can use in jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ - create one with the string you provided and then you can work with it. I know there are other references for non-jQuery use, but that's easy enough to Google

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for the pointer about CDATA. I've included it in my response as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `text` will strip the tags as you experienced. You can instead use the jQuery `children` method ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/children/)) on the transcript node to get the HTML. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gjwyd/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/xml/",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            xml: "<transcript><p>Hello, world</p></transcript>"
        },
        success: function(xml) {
            var container = $('#content');
            var html = $(xml).find('transcript').children();
            container.html(html);
        }
    });
});​
```

The key is this line:

```
var html = $(xml).find('transcript').children();
```

And being sure to set the dateType as xml.

## Issues

When taking HTML from an XML response it may be missing the default styles. For example, a paragraph tag may not have `display: block`. Resetting the styles may be one way around this issue. A more correct and probably easier way would be to put the HTML content inside of CDATA within the XML as one of the other commenters suggested.

http://jsfiddle.net/tZJQp/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/xml/",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            xml: "<transcript><![CDATA[<p>Hello, world</p><p>Bye</p>]]></transcript>"
        },
        success: function(xml) {
            var container = $('#content');
            var html = $(xml).find('transcript').text();
            container.html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

As others note, `html` won't work on XML.

Comment: This is right, but I think the OP wants literally `<p>Text</p>` put on the page.

Comment: Another important piece is `dataType: "xml"` +1

Comment: And this: "It is reasonable that html does not work as the XML returned by the AJAX request is not part of the DOM for the current document." is incorrect. You can use `.html` on non-DOM elements, you just can't use it on XML document elements

Comment: @Ian Good point on `html`. I'll update the answer. I think the OP does want it to be HTML though not text but I agree it is not 100% clear.

Comment: @Cymen Actually yeah, very true. When they differentiate between "Actual" and "Desired" outputs, I'm not sure if they mean visual output or actual output into the DOM. So good point on that :)

Comment: @Ian unless you're using IE7 or 8. Unknown tags tend to cause problems in oldIE if you don't shim them and try to treat them like any other html element.

Comment: @KevinB Good point on the dataType. I've updated the answer to highlight that.

Comment: @KevinB Are you referring to my comment that `.html` can be used on non-DOM elements?

Comment: @Ian yes, for example, IE8 wouldn't consider `<transcript></transcript>` a valid element and would drop either it, or it wouldn't be selectable, so .find("transcript") should return 0 elements if `xml` is html rather than an xml doc.

Comment: @KevinB I see I see, I just wonder if jQuery takes care of that. Now, of course, as you pointed out, IE would probably bug out when you try to insert it into the DOM, but I wonder if manipulation of it in only Javascript/jQuery would be fine. Although I can't see that really being any different, so you're probably right. At the same time, I feel like if you were manipulating non-real element types, you'd be attempting it with XML and would parse it to XML first anyways :)

Comment: Thank you everyone, Cymen that worked great, except something VERY weird happened on the page.  The paragraph tags are there... but they don't seem to be doing anything, when I inspect with firebug, it shows the margins, but the margins aren't functioning.  It's hard to explain so I'll just show you: http://www.flipmediasd.com/test2 if you scroll below the video in the transcript div you'll see what I'm referring to.

Comment: Well, I cannot figure out why the paragraph tags are not being formatted once the page is loaded. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact it's pulling html from an XML document? **confused**. I'm going to try and mess with CDATA tags as someone mentioned here.

Comment: I found a solution, putting CDATA tags around the HTML as Christophe hinted earlier worked flawlessly.  I'll post the full solution with code when this site allows me (I'm a new member so it makes me wait 6 hours before answering my own question in the thread.)

Comment: Are you using `dataType: "xml"` on your AJAX request for the XML data? If not, you could try it and see if it works. It's working in this jsfiddle...

Comment: Yes, I used the dataType: "xml", my full page is here: http://www.flipmediasd.com/test2  The .ajax function in reference is on line 108 and the code in question is on line 120 (ignore lines 113 thru 118. It was really quite weird, everything 'looked' to be working, but for whatever reason the paragraph tags were not being formatted by the browser, even though they would appear in the source.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gjwyd/2/ - I edited it to have multiple paragraphs.  Do you see how they just appear one after another, instead of spaced out like normal.  That was the prob.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gjwyd/4/ That is odd -- I tried styling `p` directly and it works however you shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: By default, paragraphs are block elements, so it didn't even cross my mind to use 'display:block'...  so strange. I suppose your method would work as well then. Still a bit confused as to why it behaves like that though.  Can you edit your answer to include this? As well as mention the CDATA alternative, and then I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Will do. I think the CDATA approach is correct after thinking about this for a bit.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Cymen, very much appreciated.  Thanks to everyone else for their input as well.